# Remote connection to Windows 8 "access is denied"

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I have set up a remote connection to my computer:

- I have checked the allow remote desktop connections:
  [image]
- I have added my user to the "The remote desktop users" list under the button "Select users"
- When I connect, I can provide my username and password, but it says that one or both is incorrect.
- I have found a post that I have to add `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` to the .rdp file. I did so, I can see the login screen of Windows and when I log in I get a message "Access is denied"

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This might be beacause the user is not allowed in local security policy.

Check: local security policy > local policy > user rights assignment > allow connection using remote desktop

The default value is "Administrators, Remote desktop users". Make sure that the connecting user is in one of this groups.

Comment: I have added my user to this list, same result.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert - Is this user administrator or not?

Comment: Yes, it is my account and it is administrator.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert - One more thing: which version do you use? Win 8 Home, Pro or Enterprise?